# Absolute Convergence of a series in Browder

Tags: real-analysis

I'm quite stuck on an exercise in Browder's Mathematical Analysis and could use a push in the right direction. The question reads:

Show that if $(a_n)$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$, and $a_nr^n \rightarrow 0$ for some $r \neq 0$, then $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{a_nx^n}{n!}}$ converges absolutely for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, I can see that the $a_n$ need not tend to zero or to converge at all (as the r might be quite small), and surely we may make the value for x as large as we like, so the convergence of the series given seems to rest solely on the fact that n! grows quite quickly.

Now, the series looks like it would lend itself well to a proof using the ratio test, but what I end up with upon computing the appropriate ratio is $$\limsup\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\rvert\cdot\frac{|x|}{n+1}$$

and I'm not sure how to proceed with the knowledge I have about $a_nr^n$. Am I moving in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \Bbb R$. Since $a_n r^n \to 0$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $|a_n r^n| < 1$ for all $n \ge N$. Thus $$\left|\frac{a_n x^n}{n!}\right| = |a_n r^n| \frac{|x/r|^n}{n!} < \frac{|x/r|^n}{n!} \quad \text{for all} \quad n\ge N.$$

Since $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{|x/r|^n}{n!}$ converges, by direct comparison the series $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a_nx^n}{n!}$ converges absolutely. Since $x$ was arbitrary, $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{a_nx^n}{n!}$ converges absolutely for every $x\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: V. slick. Also this explains why $r \neq 0$, which was bugging me. Thanks for your help!